# Android ImagePagerAdapter, Displaying Text view

Tags: java, android, image

There is my problem I use a ImagePagerAdapter for displaying a dynamical gallery of Bitmap based on an internal DB. My code actually displaying the correct Bitmap according to the position.
But i want to display a Description of the Image too (using a textView), my code displaying the description but don't give me the correct description of the img it's seems that using the variable position of instantiateItem don't return what I need.

I use Two array, where i have store the description and the bitmap.
    mydesc[] = To store the description of each img
    mydraw[] = To store my drawable

I use the position of this function

```
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
```

There is my code for the ImagePager

```
private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
   @Override
   // Count the element on my array
    public int getCount() {
          return mydraw.length;   
    }

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
      return view == ((ImageView) object);
}


  /**
   * Target: Displaying the data according to the position
   * 
   * 
   * @param container, position
   * @return imageView,  The view displaying in the page
   */
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    Context context = MainActivitySocialisation.this;
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
    //TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
      R.dimen.padding_medium);

    // Display the current image
    imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(mydraw[position]); //(mImages[position]);

    // Display the name of the Image    
    textView.setText(mydesc[position]);  

    ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView,0);
    return imageView;
}
```

Thanks you for your help,

Comment: where did you initialized the textView?

Comment: textView is public and i can acces to it, and change the value without problems.
    public TextView textView;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution for my problems i have set a listener to my viewpager and use

```
    viewPager.getCurrentItem();
```